# Understanding $l_p$ with the metric $\rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider a  successions space $l_p$, for $p\geqslant1$ in which $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k...)$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x_0$. The metric defined is the following $\rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}$
Since the series converges $\forall \epsilon>0\exists\:n_0,\forall n\geqslant n_0$ $\rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}{1+|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}<\epsilon$.$k=1,2,3...$

**Question:**

I do not understand the $k$ in the following metric $\rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}{1+|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}$. Does the $k$ indicator implies the sequence (series) is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Does the $k$ stands for each variable in which the sequence converges in the following way $|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|$ for each $k$? If not what is the meaning of $k$?

Comment: $x_{k}$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ element of the sequence $x$. Similarly for $y$...

Comment: @Mark        Why does the author write $x_{n,k}$ and $x_{0,k}$ if $n$ and $0$ must equal some element of $k$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Can you refer to your source?

Comment: What does $x_{n,k}$ mean? It seems as if you've only defined the sequence $\{x_k\}$.

Comment: @user144410 These are notes from a class of Introduction to  Functional Analysis.

Comment: @PedroGames, If possible you should share it here; otherwise, you need to  clarify your question: what is the presented argument about? Is it showing that the metric is well-defined? It seems to me that you are talking about subsequences here when you use the notations $x_{n,k}$?

Comment: @David Thanks for your reply. But  $x_{n,k}$ meaning is precisely what I want to know. I began to think it was a sequence defined in a $\mathbb{R}^m\:\:,m\in\mathbb{N}$. so the author was using $k$ to include more then $m$ dimensions. But that sounds ,I guess, a little bit far-fetched.

Comment: @user144410 The author introduces the metric in the following way:$x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k,...)$ a sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$, then $x_n=(x_{n,1}...,x_{n,k},...)$ then the author shows that as $|x_n(k)-x_0(k)|\to 0\:\:N\to \infty$ so does $ \rho(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}{1+|x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|}<\epsilon$. I guess that the sub-sequence idea that you proposed might be right.

Comment: @PedroGomes Alright. I think its an argument about the completeness of the space under the given metric. See the answer that I will refer to below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to your questions is given by the accepted answer of the following question: [The space of sequences as a complete metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58759/the-space-of-sequences-as-a-complete-metric-space)

You need to notice that there are two notion of convergence here: pointwise convergence, and the convergence of the sequence itself as an element of the $\ell_p$ space. That is:
\begin{equation}
x_n := \{x_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell_p
\end{equation}
$\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of sequences: $x_1$ is the first sequence, $x_2$ is the second ..etc each of them has infinite coordinates since they are elements of the space $\ell_p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could not I see it? Finally I understood as in the function space, it is the distance between the function, in $l_p$ is the distance between the sequences. Tomorrow I award you the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Really I want us to look into it this way. Let
```

$ \textbf{x}=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}, ...)$ 
be a vector in an infinite dimension. The sequence of vector $ \textbf{x}$ can be denoted by 
$$ \{  \textbf{x}_k  \} = \{ x_{n,k}\} = \{ x_{0,k},x_{1,k},...,x_{n,k},...\} $$
    so, in the metric in question, $n$ is just a subscript denoting the $n^{th}$ component of the vector $\textbf{x}$. And $k$ is a subscript that denote the $k^{th}$ term in the sequence of vector $\textbf{x}_k$. In fact, $ |x_{n,k}-x_{0,k}|$ can be seen as sequence of distances between each term  $x_{k,n}$ and a particular point $x_{0,k}$