# Are the following statements correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I am given a set of sequences $S = \{(x_n)_n | x_n \in \{0, 1\}\}$ and the following function:
$$d(x, y) = \sum_n \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{2^n}, x, y \in S.$$

Noting that the series is strictly positive, as is the fraction, are the following statements correct?

1. $d(x,x) = 0 \iff |x_n - x_n| = 0$
2. $d(x, y) = d(y, x) \iff |x_n - y_n| = |y_n - x_n|$
3. $d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z) \iff |x_n - y_n| + |y_n - z_n| \ge |x_n - z_n|$

Comment: They shouldn't be phrased as equivalences (using $\Leftrightarrow$).  Instead, the statement $d(x, x) = 0$ is true, with proof: $|x_n - x_n| = 0$ for all $n$.  Also, do we assume $n \geq 0$?

Comment: @Shaun You are right about the first one, but are the next two correctly phrased?

Comment: To check that $d$ is indeed a distance you also have to show that the series is always convergent. Now, you have to show that the axioms which define a distance are indeed satisfied by $d$. So, you have to check that if $d(x,y)=0$ then the sequences $x$ and $y$ are the same, the symmetry is quite obvious and the triangle inequality follow from what you wrote at 3. after the $\iff$. But you have to write it in a more rigorous way.

Comment: @PaulManta All of the statements should be phrased in a similar way.  What is to the left of $\Leftrightarrow$ is a (true) statement, and you should follow it with the proof of the statement.  As to what you have written, your reasoning for 2 and 3 seems to be missing essential details (if this were a HW, I'd grade it less than half credit due to missing details).

Comment: Hint:  The definition of $d(x,y)$ involves a sum and some powers of $2$.  Those items ought to be part of your proof as well.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472516/how-to-prove-that-this-series-is-a-metric-dx-y-sum-i-0-infty-fracx-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do minor changes:

1. $d(x,x) = 0 \iff |x_n - x_n| = 0$; If you used the implication $(\forall n\in\mathbb N)|x_n - x_n| = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x,x)=0$ instead, it would seem a little clearer to me.
2. $d(x, y) = d(y, x) \iff |x_n - y_n| = |y_n - x_n|$; Again I would write this as $(\forall n\in\mathbb N) |x_n - y_n| = |y_n - x_n|$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$
3. $d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z) \iff |x_n - y_n| + |y_n - z_n| \ge |x_n - z_n|$; the same thing here.

In the first two cases it is perhaps not so important, but in the third one the implication $\Longrightarrow$ is not true.

---

In case you have already learned something about products of topological spaces, you will find out that this is in fact the [Cantor space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space). This metric is explicitly mentioned e.g. in Banach Space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis By Marián Fabian, Petr Habala et al., [p.739](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA739)

---

BTW is there a name for this metric? It is neither [Fréchet metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21552/w-space-of-all-sequences-with-frechet-metric) $d_F$ nor [Baire metric](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC&pg=PA130) $d_B$. 
$$d_F(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}$$
$$d_B(x,y)=\frac1{\min\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n\ne y_n\}} \qquad\text{for }x\ne y$$
These two metrics are used frequently for sequences space and their natural generalizations can be used to define topology on countable product of metric spaces.